# htaccess - remove .php extension and keep variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

original url - `example.com/stars.php?id=9&s=lorem-ipsum`
want to be - `example.com/stars/9/lorem-ipsum`

here is my try - getting error 500

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/stars\.php\?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /stars.php?id=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

.htaccess and stars.php are placed in the root - example.com

pls help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule to handle external redirection to user friendly URL here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(stars)\.php\?id=(\d+)&s=([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

##Rule to handle non-existing files/directories should be served by php files in backend.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&s=$3 [L]
```

Comment: I clear the cache and tried. There is no error but there is no pretty url also. Address bar is - `example.com/stars.php?id=9&s=lorem-ipsum`. Also, I want to rewrite only if current page is `stars.php` and not `planets.php` - for example.

Comment: @vegas,ok, could you please try my edited rules once?

Comment: now I'm getting this - `example.com/stars/9/lorem-ipsum?id=9&s=lorem-ipsum`

Comment: @vegas, ok there was 1 typo, I have fixed it now, kindly do check it once and let me know then? cheers

Comment: it works. thanks a lot for all your efforts. I'll be crazy with all about htaccess

Comment: @vegas, Your welcome, keep posting good questions and answers on this great site, cheers and happy learning :)